# Pulling data from database and into an html table

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm pulling data from a database but only getting the first row into the dynamically produced html table.

I've tried adding another foreach loop but that isn't the answer… I'm out of ideas...

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jeuxvideo', $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jeuxvideo";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$request = $result->execute();

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Id</td><td>Titre</td><td>Prix<td>Date de Sortie</td><td>Genre</td><td>Origine</td><td>Mode</td><td>Connexion</td></tr>\n";
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

This code pulls all the correct info and puts it in the right place in the html table, but for some Reason it doesn't collect the Following rows data...

Comment: Use `fetchAll` and put your `<tr>...</tr>` inside your `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks @waterloomatt, close but no cigar. The second row is getting pulled now, but both show up as an array, not the seperate columns in the table. Any thoughts?

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\laragon\www\CRUD\treatment.php on line 23

Comment: Remove `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: How many columns are in this query? Best practice in SQL: avoid `*` by using named columns in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line only fetches one row:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You need to fetch as many rows it can give you. Once there are no more rows to fetch the function will return `FALSE`, so you can use with the `while` loop, like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Two loops seem excessive for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any variables you need prepared for your query, you can simply do:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jeuxvideo');

echo '<table>';

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';

    echo "<td>$row['name']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['url']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['timestamp']</td>";

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

A 2nd method would be:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jeuxvideo');

echo '<table>';

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr>';

    echo "<td>$row['name']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['url']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['timestamp']</td>";

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jeuxvideo', $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jeuxvideo";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$request = $result->execute();

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Id</td><td>Titre</td><td>Prix<td>Date de Sortie</td><td>Genre</td><td>Origine</td><td>Mode</td><td>Connexion</td></tr>\n";

$row = $request->fetch_all();

echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```